# What to do in case of missing feedback on an idea?

Tags: discussion

I recently posted this question [Bellman-Ford for Matching Problems?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226059/bellman-ford-for-matching-problems) on MO and got an answer stating that the occurence of negative odd cycles would be inevitable.
Upon reading that claim, I had an idea of how to guarantee, that odd negative cycles do not occur; that idea has been integrated into an edit of the question.

Meanwhile, I have checked that idea for flaws several times, but could not find one.
However, there was no feedback on that idea, despite my impression, that it could be interesting from an algorithmic point of view.

Now my question is, how to proceed (if at all)? 
Should I put that idea into an answer along with proof-ideas to raise the level of attention (make it CW) or would you advise me to do something else (e.g. wait till an expert in the field finds the time to look at it)?

Answer (score 3):

If your idea really *answers* your question, at least partially, then you can post it as an answer.  But doing so may actually *decrease* the attention attracted by your question: if someone sees on the front page that the question has many answers, they may assume it is effectively resolved and that they may not be able to add much.

Adding an answer will have the effect of "bumping" the question back to the front page.  But your edit already did that.

In the Stack Exchange model, the intended way to simply draw additional attention to your question is to [offer a bounty](https://mathoverflow.net/help/bounty), which creates a reputation incentive for someone to try to answer the question to your satisfaction, if they can.

But ultimately, you can't force people to take an interest in your question, or to have productive ideas about it.  As Yogi Berra allegedly said, "If people don't want to come out to the ball park, nobody can stop them."

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Nate. It convinced me not to try to attract further attention to the idea on MO; rather I will implement it to get confidence about its correctness and efficiency. The main benefit would anyhow be a simpler algorithmic solution of the general matching problem, If the idea proofs useful, then it will automatically attract attention after some time even if not necessarily on MO..